# MahApps.Metro MetroWindow.ShowMessageAsync does not exist

Tags: c#, mahapps.metro, .net-4.7

I just installed MahApps.Metro from nuget (version 1.5.0.23). The tutorial on the homepage tells me to open dialogs via

`this.ShowMessageAsync(...)  // in MainWindow : MetroWindow`

but this method (or any other `ShowXYZ` method) does not exist.

How do I open my dialog? Do I have to use the `DialogCoordinator`?

### Update

I've overseen that this is an extension method (which forces me to use the `this` qualifier, which I didn't).

Comment: `ShowMessageAsync` is an extension method. Do you include the `MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs` namespace?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035029/dirk) in the comments, `ShowMessageAsync` is an extension method, sou you have to use the `Dialogs` namespace.

Just add the using and you should be fine:

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;
```